# Pooling:more than one connection to a database

Tags: sql-server, sql, connectivity, connection-pooling

I have a doubt that whether Pooling actually works with vb.net.
I used below query to check the connection to the database from different pc.

```
SELECT hostname,p.status,[program_name],loginame,name
FROM Master..sysprocesses  as p join master.dbo.sysdatabases as  d on p.dbID = d.dbID
WHERE p.ecid=0 and p.hostname<>'' 
order by name
```

In the output i saw more than one connection from a pc to the same database.

So i got doubt about this.In my vb.net application i open connection only once so i was thinking like the connection will be used from same pool,so there will be only one open connection to a database from a PC.

**UPDATE**

I have a vb.net application which makes use of connection to SQL server databases.

1. If i open a multiple instances of same program then connection will be drawn from same pool or different pool?
2. If we open different exe but both open connection to same databases then same connection pool will be used by both?

When we run query in SQL server many connections are shown to same DB from same PC.

Comment: There can be one connection, but multiple SPIDs spawned by sql server. Are you sure that you are not referring to multiple threads spawned by sql server as multiple connections ? Can you post a screenshot so we can help you better ?

Comment: @Kin I didn't get you.Which screenshot you are referring to?

Comment: can you describe what you refer to `In the output i saw more than one connection from a pc to the same database.` ?

Comment: I've voted to migrate this to Stack Overflow. Really this is going to be an analysis of your source code and connection string, so if you could edit those things into the question proactively, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pooling does not guarantee a single connection. For each concurrently active (logical) connection you need one physical connection. So if you have 10 threads each using a connection instance, or for some reason are opening 10 connections on a single thread, you will see 10 physical connections.

A single session is assigned to a single connection. Each connection can have at most one session at the same time.

Comment: Different processes don't share connections ever. Whether it is the same "exe" or not is irrelevant to the issue. The OS cares about processes only.

Comment: Then pooling is useful when connection to same database is opened more than once in same thread right? What happens if we open a separate thread & open connection to same database (i.e. pooling is used across multiple threads?)?

Comment: In the same process the pool is shared across threads (shared memory space). That's going to work. (Actually, the pool is per AppDomain but that doesn't matter most of the time).

Comment: How can i change my application so that it uses Appdomain.Is there any easy method?

Comment: Can you please tell how to make my application to use Appdomain?