# Connection pooling and Appdomain

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, connection-pooling

This question is related to my old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934643/poolingmore-than-one-connection-to-a-database) .

1) I have a vb.net application which requires connections to some databases.So now if i open multiple instance of same application(exe files) then it uses different connection or uses multiple connection. So can i make it to use single connection?

2) I heard about Appdomain(An AppDomain provides a layer of isolation within a process) . Does it help in making the connection to be drawn from same pool and make optimal use of resources?
This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6578/Use-AppDomains-To-Reduce-Memory-Consumption-in-NET) has something related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different processes (your case #1) do not (and cannot) share database connections, each connection is unique to the process.

I do not know whether connection pools are per process or per-appdomain.<sup>1</sup> But it is unlikely to make much difference. The model that you should be aiming for is to create, use and then close connections around each functional database operation. Do not try and keep them open, rather try and keep them closed. This maximises the re-use opportunities for re-use.

Unless you have a particular will a few excess connections over what is theoretically needed the default pooling while avoiding holding connections open will just work.

---

<sup>1</sup> As connections are reset before being returned from the pool it would be rather hard to determine which of these is the case. Perhaps a test program that had one app domain open, use and close one connection before another app domain repeated the process and see if one or two connections to the database were established.

Comment: "Connections are pooled per process, per application domain, per connection string and when integrated security is used, per Windows identity" -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Answer (score 0):

Each AppDomain would have its own Connection Pool, so no I don't think using AppDomains would help in your case.